# Prevent your Questions from "getting lost"

Tags: discussion, support

There are an awful lot of questions asked in this Q&A Sites, especially on Stack Overflow. Now I wonder if a question can get lost, simply because it didn't get much attention, since it is quickly pushed back from newer questions. Is there some way to prevent this from happening? Or is it automatically prevented by some way (Tags, etc.) and if I don't get many views, I can assume it's because I didn't ask properly or the question simply isn't of interest to most users?

Comment: Placing a bounty and editing to improve the question typically provide questions additional views.

Comment: **Editing bumps** actually to the _active queue_!

Comment: Yes, and if've just seen you can find the answer in the help-center too. Should i delete this question?

Comment: Tags are important. Use the broader language tag because experts subscribe to find questions to answer. If you hover your mouse over each tag, you can see the number of subscribers for each tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Imho, it's mostly two problems: a) Reputation-seeking users are quick to note that they're better off answering trivial questions rather than harder ones. b) High rep users tend to get bored of weeding through the scores of low quality questions, and therefor miss out on questions that aren't promoted by a bounty or tags using their favorite low traffic tags.